# How to associate data sent by a user to his own account in Django

Tags: django

I have a model called KeyFormModel which has 2 fields "secret_key" and "primary_key", I pointed this model towards a form and called this form to a view and template. each user has exactly one primary_key and one secret_key, when I send this to model they are mixing with other keysets

this is my model

```
class KeyFormModel(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    primary_key = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    secret_key = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return username+"_keys"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Keys'
```

this is my form

```
from ..models import KeyFormModel
from django import forms
from django.conf import settings
class KeyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    primary_key = forms.CharField(required=True)
    secret_key = forms.CharField(required=True,widget = forms.PasswordInput)
    
    class Meta:
        model = KeyFormModel
        fields = ("username","primary_key","secret_key")
```

this is my view

```
@cache_control(no_cache=True, must_revalidate=True)
@login_required(login_url='../login')
def AccountView(request):
    
    if(request.method == 'POST'):
        form =KeyForm(request.POST)
        if(form.is_valid()):
            form.save()
        else:
            for msg in form.error_messages:
                messages.error(request,f"{msg}")
        
        
    form = KeyForm
    return(render(request, 'accountView.html',context={"form":form}))
```

as you can see I am trying to add username from AUTH_USER_MODEL after logging into that account but failing miserably. please hlp

Comment: What is the error message / stack trace?

Comment: error varies with changes main problem is I am unable to associate data sent by a user to him which makes it impossible to retrieve. lets say user abc sent one set of keys and user ghj  sent another set of keys, how to differentiate them and provide access to the data which they have created?

Comment: I think you should override save model in your ModelForm and check actions there

Answer (score 0):

What worked out for me:

import User to models:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

and in the specific model add user field:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(
    User,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
)
```

Comment: how should form look like?

Comment: it doesn't work by the way  https://imgur.com/IpQxcW0   user is still empty

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer

```
@cache_control(no_cache=True, must_revalidate=True)
@login_required(login_url='../login')
def AccountView(request):
    keyforce=KeyFormModel.objects.filter(user=request.user)         
    if(keyforce):
        return(render(request,'keyView.html',{"keys":keyforce}))
    else:
        if(request.method == 'POST'):
            form = KeyForm(request.POST)
            if(form.is_valid()):
                primary_key = request.POST['primary_key']
                secret_key = request.POST['secret_key']
                new = KeyFormModel(primary_key=primary_key,
                                secret_key=secret_key, user=request.user)
                new.save()
                return(redirect("main:Account"))
            else:
                for msg in form.error_messages:
                    messages.error(request, f'{msg}')
        else:
            form = KeyForm
        
        return(render(request, 'accountView.html', context={"form": form}))
```

I learned that the values to the models can be added through views itself,

all I did was something like this

after adding User to your model

in view create

form = yourModel(user = request.user)

voila its done